# Accessing Solution Method Information with Backslash Operator in Sparse Matrix Solving (SparseArrays.jl)

Tags: debugging, julia, sparse-matrix

Is there a way to obtain information about the method used by the backslash operator in SparseArrays.jl when solving a system of equations? If not, is there an alternative approach or workaround to gather this information during the solving process? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

I am applying the backslash operator with matrices in CSC form. However, I couldn't find, at least in the Julia documentation, any parameter to retrieve the method used to solve the system. I attempted to use the @less macro to inspect the code that has been called, but the output is extensive, making it challenging to trace the execution flow.

```julia
using SparseArrays
using LinearAlgebra

A = sprand(1000, 1000, 0.01)
c = sprand(1000, 1, 0.01)


b = @edit A \ c
```

Comment: In the Julia REPL, the `@edit` macro before an expression opens up the editor on the top-level function used to evaluate the expression. It may answer your question. P.S. add a runnable example demonstrating the problem you wish to solve